# can Samsung note 2 and j2 prime runs in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, android-virtual-device

I use android studio and I ask about, can I connect the Samsung galaxy note 2 and Samsung galaxy j2 prime plus to android studio and run the flutter app on this device

I didn't find any tutorial on youtube and I need help...

Comment: As @Tim Brückner already told, it should be possible to activate the developer mode on any android smartphone and start developing for that devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should also work with your phones. You might need to enable development mode first and maybe install some drivers.

From the Samsung homepage:

1. Plug your Samsung mobile device into your computer using a USB cable
2. If you are using a Windows computer, go to Samsung Android USB Driver for Windows, then download and install the USB driver onto your computer
3. Enable developer options on your device by going to Settings > About device > Software info and tapping Build number seven times. (Devices with Android 4.1 or older already have developer options displayed by default.)
4. Turn on USB debugging by tapping Settings > Developer options > USB debugging

See all the details here: https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/galaxy-sdk-getting-started.html